# Activiti: potentialStarter method not work

Tags: activiti

I defined my process like:

```
<process id="myProcess"
             name="My process"
             isExecutable="true"
             activiti:candidateStarterUsers="MANAGER"
             activiti:candidateStarterGroups="MANAGER">
....
```

**Problem:**

The *groups* and *users* lists are empty after:

```
List<Group> groups = identityService.createGroupQuery().potentialStarter("myProcess").list();
List<User> users = identityService.createUserQuery().potentialStarter("myProcess").list();
```

No matter I proceed those queries bofore or after process start.

**Question:**

What the reason?

Comment: Which version of Activiti you are using? what do you mean by its does not work? Does it throw any exception, if yes then edit the question.

Comment: it means that after process definition above the groups and users list are empty. Before I start the process I want to check if current user have access to start it. identityService.createGroupQuery().potentialStarter("myProcess").list().size() == 0 ((\